# java xmx parameter seems not working in CentOS 7.6, how to limit java 11 process memory

Tags: java

Now I am using this command to start my Java 11 app in CentOS 7.6:

```
nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -jar \
  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=0.0.0.0:5019 \
  ${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME} >> ./cruise.log &
```

I have limit this app maxium using 256MB of memory(the Host machine only have 2GB memory), but the app always killed by the Linux OOM Killer. I am using this command to check if the Java process killed by linux kernel:

```
dmesg | grep java
```

shows log like this:

```
[6768976.753187] java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[6768976.754518] java cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[6768976.755264] CPU: 0 PID: 1480 Comm: java Kdump: loaded Tainted: G            E  ------------   3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1
[6768976.830305] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6768976.845210] [12175]     0 12175   690412   140078     432        0             0 java
[6768976.974348] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6768976.993705] [12175]     0 12175   690412   140078     432        0             0 java
[6768977.360880] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6768977.375595] [12175]     0 12175   690412   140078     432        0             0 java
[6772518.650946] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6772518.665056] [12175]     0 12175   690412   140119     432        0             0 java
[6776216.737728] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6776216.753942] [12175]     0 12175   690412   140197     432        0             0 java
[6779968.759144] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6779968.774794] [12175]     0 12175   690412   140750     432        0             0 java
[6783751.768168] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6783751.783042] [12175]     0 12175   690412   140903     432        0             0 java
[6830220.412373] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6830220.430240] [16695]     0 16695   644884    89569     273        0             0 java
[6830220.555033] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6830220.576297] [16695]     0 16695   644884    89569     273        0             0 java
[6851842.309817] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6851842.323408] [16695]     0 16695   647237    99529     289        0             0 java
[6851842.447896] [ 1282]     0  1282   518681    17582      95        0             0 java
[6851842.462193] [16695]     0 16695   647237    99529     289        0             0 java
[6851842.485439] Out of memory: Kill process 16695 (java) score 205 or sacrifice child
[6851842.486780] Killed process 16695 (java), UID 0, total-vm:2588948kB, anon-rss:398116kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

why the Java did not OOM itself and using so much memory and finally killed by linux kernel? How to limit java process memory usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-Xmx` flag only limits the Java heap size. It doesn't constrains the JVM's other use of memory.  The JVM uses / consumes off-heap memory for lots of things:

- The shared memory segments for the `java` executable itself
- Dynamically loaded (native) libraries.
- The JVM's (C++) native heap
- The Java threads' stack segments
- The JVM's metaspace
- Memory segments for mapped files, etc.

Depending on the application and what it does, this odd-heap memory could be significant.

(The `-Xmx` option does work, but not in the way that you think it does.)

---

> Why the Java did not OOM itself and using so much memory ...

Presumably because it hasn't totally filled the Java heap.  (Or hasn't failed to allocate an off-memory segment.)

> ... and finally killed by linux kernel?

The OOM killer doesn't actually kill based on the absolute amount of (physical or virtual) memory that a process uses.  What it is actually doing is measuring the demand that the various processes are placing on the virtual memory system (swapping) and picking the process that *seems* to be causing the system to thrash.

A JVM running a full garbage collection on a system that with a limited amount of RAM is liable to generate a lot of paging, and is liable to be an OOM killer target.